# What nocturnal animal sound am I hearing in the trees in Maine?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, trees, bioacoustics

Every year, during late summer nights (usually around 9:00 pm) in Maine, I hear a noise coming from high up in the trees. The trees I hear it from are mostly maple or conifer, but where I live there are few trees that are not. It sounds like a [cardinal's chirp](http://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Northern_Cardinal/sounds) (fourth sound down in link), but longer, scratchier, and lower pitch. The sound starts and ends abruptly. There are three to six chirps in a row from the same tree, and then silence for a few minutes. Sometimes I will hear it again after a few minutes from the same tree and sometimes from a different tree. The skies are usually clear when I hear it. No one else in my family can hear it. I live in a suburban area, but when I go to a more densely forested area I hear it more frequently. Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: I think this question might be better fit for [The Great Outdoors SE](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/). There might be some people there who are more familiar with bird calls than the people here in Biology SE.

Comment: @AleksandrH I did ask it there a few months ago, but no one has answered it.

Comment: 1. Do you have a recording of the actual sound itself? 2. What time of night do you hear the sound? 3. Have you noticed what the weather is like prior to and during the time you hear the sound? 4. How high up in the tree is the sound?

Comment: 5. What kind (i.e., species) of trees are you hearing the sound from?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/maine-birds/nvlvEqggNjo

Comment: @theforestecologist That sounds like my situation, except the sound I am hearing is definitely not a spring peeper.

Comment: @IOWF ok so please answer some more questions or provide more info

Comment: Do you typically hear what sounds like one individual, or a couple "talking"  back and forth,  or does it seem like there are many making the sound?  If many, how many (dozens, 100s?) and do they overlap in making the sound?

Comment: @IOWF Did you want an answer to this question? You've neglected to provide additional necessary info (i.e., answering any of the questions proposed to you in the comments) for over a year now. I see you're still active on the site, so please respond if you're interested in getting a positive ID or if you have any updates. Thanks.

Comment: I have been hearing this sound all summer after dark, I live in southern Maine. I just got home from work (December 2nd) and I'm hearing it again. Must be something nocturnal to be out this late! (10:30pm) I will try to record it.

Comment: since you don't have a recording of the sound you might be better off on a birding site where thy will have samples of songs you can listen too, just going from your description it could be anything even a tree frog.

Answer (score 2):

My initial guess (knowing almost no information) is that it's a Northern saw-whet owl (*Aegolius acadicus*). These owls live year round in Maine but also increase in number as some migrate from Canada through Maine for winter. You can hear their advertising song [here](https://www.allaboutbirds.org/guide/Northern_Saw-whet_Owl/sounds).

Northern Saw-whet Owls have a distinctive *too-too-too* call -- an insistent series of whistled notes on roughly the same pitch, given at a rate of about 2 notes per second. Males calling to advertise their territory can be heard up to half a mile away. Other males respond with a softer, faster, lower version of the call.

Comment: Thanks, but its not the one. The noise I hear is similar, but scratchier and less frequent.

Comment: Darn. Ok. Please provide more info so that we can try to figure this out. Please answer my questions in the comments under your question.

Comment: You still deserve a +1 :)